# regex regular expression to match most of URLs needs improvement

Tags: php, regex, function, url, double-quotes

I need a function which will check for the existing URLs in a string.

```
function linkcleaner($url) {
$regex="(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))";

if(preg_match($regex, $url, $matches)) {
echo $matches[0];
}
}
```

The regular expression is taken from the [John Gruber's blog](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls), where he addressed the problem of creating a regex matching all the URLs.
Unfortunately, I can't make it work. It seems the problem is coming from the double quotes inside the regex or the other punct symbols at the end of the expression.
Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: "Can't make it work" is not a built-in PHP error message.

Comment: sorry, the error was "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\...\config.php on line ...". English is not my native, sometimes I have problems explaining what I want to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from @tandu's answer, you also need delimiters for a regex in php.

The easiest would be to start and end your pattern with an `#` as that character does not appear in it:

```
$regex="#(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))#";
```

Comment: @poncha It does not appear in this regex pattern and that is the only thing that matters here.

Comment: @jeroen it claims to match "all the URLs" ;) does it not?

Comment: @poncha I have not checked the regex very well, but you can take a white-list approach or a black-list approach. It seems the OP is taking a blacklist approach: `[^`. Either way, the character does not appear in the pattern, so it's safe to use a as a delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `"` with a `\`

Answer (score 1):

Jack Maney's comment...EPIC :D

On a more serious note, it does not work because you terminated the string literal right in the middle.

To include a double quote (`"`) in a string, you need to escape it using a `\`

So, the line will be

```
$regex="/(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/";
```

Notice I've escaped the (`'`) as well. That is for when you define a string between 2 single quotes.

Comment: thank you & @tandu 
I still get an error Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '\' in C:\wamp\www\...\config.php on line 919

Comment: I think in php you need to delimit the regex by the same character at the start and end. I've edited my answer to delimit using `/`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you guys read this regex, cause it's a real pain to read/modify... ;)

try this (this is not a one-liner, yes, but it is easy to understand and modify if needed):

```
<?php
$re_proto = "(?:https?|ftp|gopher|irc|whateverprotoyoulike)://";
$re_ipv4_segment = "[12]?[0-9]{1,2}";
$re_ipv4 = "(?:{$re_ipv4_segment}[.]){3}".$re_ipv4_segment;
$re_hostname = "[a-z0-9_]+(?:[.-][a-z0-9_]+){0,}";
$re_hostname_fqdn = "[a-z0-9_](?:[a-z0-9_-]*[.][a-z0-9]+){1,}";
$re_host = "(?:{$re_ipv4}|{$re_hostname})";
$re_host_fqdn = "(?:{$re_ipv4}|{$re_hostname_fqdn})";
$re_port = ":[0-9]+";
$re_uri = "(?:/[a-z0-9_.%-]*){0,}";
$re_querystring = "[?][a-z0-9_.%&=-]*";
$re_anchor = "#[a-z0-9_.%-]*";
$re_url = "(?:(?:{$re_proto})(?:{$re_host})|{$re_host_fqdn})(?:{$re_port})?(?:{$re_uri})?(?:{$re_querystring})?(?:{$re_anchor})?";

$text = <<<TEXT
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/some/path/to/file.php?f1=v1&f2=v2#foo
http://localhost.localdomain/
http://localhost/docs/???
www....wwhat?
www.example.com
ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/latest/
Some new Mary-Kate Olsen pictures I found: the splendor of the Steiner Street Picture of href… http://t.co/tJ2NJjnf
TEXT;

$count = preg_match_all("\01{$re_url}\01is", $text, $matches);
var_dump($count);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Comment: Your answer is greate! It's the only regex wich correctly parse the following string: `RT @JustBrelieve: “@enn4xor: #TBT Last summer. *_* http://t.co/LsasKwfe”you cute , you cute .`

Comment: I've found out some problems `$re_hostname_fqdn` parameter. It matchs `Mary-Kate` as URL in `Some new Mary-Kate Olsen pictures I found: the splendor of the Steiner Street Picture of href… http://t.co/tJ2NJjnf`

Comment: @Oleg `$re_hostname_fqdn` would match `Mary-Kate`, because it's a probable hostname (as any word...), but why is it matching witout proto.. i'll look into this, thanks for noticing

Comment: Oh, you're right... `$re_hostname_fqdn` actually should not pick it up, as `$re_hostname` would and this would require a proto before it. fixing.

Comment: @Oleg changed `$re_hostname_fqdn` to `"[a-z0-9_](?:[a-z0-9_-]*[.][a-z0-9]+){1,}";`. try now

Comment: Yep, now it works in even in this case. Thanks for fast reply!